# How can I access files copied to a USB drive from a Mac, in Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, microsoft-powerpoint

I copied a bunch of PowerPoint files from a Mac to my USB drive.  When I plugged it into my Windows PC, instead of seeing a folder, I see 2-3 files:

```
week1 *
._ week1 *
._.Trashes
```

(where * is some character that I'm not sure how to type, but it looks like a dot)

If I open the files in a Hex editor - I can see some plain text:

**week1***

```
(Users/students/Documents/Students week 1
8Macintosh HD:Users: students: Documents: Students week 1
```

**._ week1***

```
Mac OS X   
fdrpMACS
```

Can anyone tell me how I can open these files in Windows?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what format the USB drive was formatted in.  If you are looking to try it again, I would go simple and format it with FAT32.  There is a program out there at: http://www.mediafour.com/products/macdrive6 that should allow you to read a Mac formatted drive in Windows, though I've never tried it.

Comment: As @NewProgrammerJames points out, to get a disk to work on multiple platforms it is by far easiest to format the disk to a suitable filesystem that all your intended OSes can read/write to natively. FAT32 is very common with USB sticks but any disk can be formatted to FAT32 (with some exceptions and maximum partition size limitations).

Comment: The very presence of dot underscore files would say it's not an HFS+ drive anyway... not that that fact answers the question...

Answer (score 2):

First: the files with names that start with "._" are [AppleDouble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleSingle_and_AppleDouble_formats) files that store Mac-specific metadata about the corresponding plain files. This information is usually not needed (at least, not for the types of files that're usable on Windows) and can be ignored or deleted.

Second: the "week1*" is an alias to a folder created with the OS X Finder. I can tell from the string "fdrpMACS" in its AppleDouble file -- this is the Mac type ("fdrp") and creator ("MACS") codes, which indicate that it's a folder alias file (in this case, the metadata was important!). From what you see in the plain file, it looks like it's an alias to "Users/students/Documents/Students week 1". I don't know if you need it for anything, but it won't do any good on Windows.